# UIButton below UITableView cannot be clicked

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, events, uiscrollview

I have a Table View with [APParallaxHeader](https://github.com/apping/APParallaxHeader). This creates a view behind the table, which acts as the header of it. My problem is, that I cannot click anything in this header. I've tried overriding `-hitTest` of the `UITableView`, but had no success.

Here is my view controller:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "UIScrollView+APParallaxHeader.h"

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    [button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ping) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.tableView addParallaxWithView:button andHeight:320];
}

- (void)ping
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

**EDIT:**
My further investigation shows, that the problem can be reduced to a simple `UIButton` below a `UITableView`. How can you get the tap events with the button?

Comment: For me it's works like a charm: http://postimg.org/image/cuhg8gzdj/
Tested in iOS 6 & 7

Comment: Are you sure that it works on iOS 7 too? For me it works only on iOS 6.

Comment: Anyway I ended up writing my own version of the parallax scroller. The trick is to overwrite `UITableView`'s `-pointInside:withEvent`. This shall return NO if the click happens in the header.